# SP2016: sharepoint fatal error -2147024809 system.argumentexception

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

There is a question. In sharpeint 2016 there is a table with several columns. ID and Position. also service information (by whom created, by whom changed)
When scanning or saving this list, an error appears:
sharepoint fatal error -2147024809 system.argumentexception

[image]

Sorry that the log as a picture attached)

Comment: Who faced, is there a solution to this problem?
This problem provides a lot of obstacles for further work.

I came across an article while searching for a solution to my problem. But I'm not sure that it is firstly connected with my problem and what else will help

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.uniqueconstraint?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: This is some kind of you private log you attached, you need to check ULS logs, enable verbose logging if you need to drill more into the details of the issue.